# How to get positions of your portfolio from Interactive Brokers with python IBPy?

Tags: programming, interactive-brokers

I am using IBPy to get the positions of my portfolio. I understand that I can do:

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection
tws = ibConnection( host = 'localhost',port= 7496, clientId = 123)
tws.reqAccountUpdates(True,'accountnumber')
```

and then I am supposed to use `updatePortfolio()` in some way, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IB API calls your code asynchronously when there are account updates after you have called reqAccountUpdates. But you have to provide a callback function (handler) for the IB API to call.

Looks like from the [ibPy documentation example]
(https://code.google.com/p/ibpy/wiki/IbPyOptional)
and how the [Java IB API](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/api.htm)
is defined, you want to call

```
tws.register(your_update_portfolio_handler,message.updatePortfolio)
```

where your_update_handler is a function you define to handle account updates.

You probably need to look through the ibPy code to confirm 'updatePortfolio' is indeed what should be passed to tws.register.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive Brokers posted a recorded webinar at youtube on Dec 13 2016.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hogXB07OJ_I
The topic is to use IBridgePy, a flexiable and easy-to-use python tool to trade at IB. You can easily get the positions in IBridgePy.

Comment: The least you could do is add a disclaimer indicating you are the author of `IBridgePy`